# Labeled Data set (For Insider Threat Detection)

Tags: security, computer-forensics

I'm implementing a machine learning for insider threat detection. Are there any labeled data set available for a supervised learning module?

Answer (score 0):

Check following resources:

- Carnegie Mellon's SEI [Insider threat Test Dataset](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/library/asset-view.cfm?assetid=508099)

ISO-CERT has an awesome compilation on incidents (that you should filter to fit your needs) since 2010 [here](https://ics-cert.us-cert.gov/advisories), aside from this, if you have enough time to ask for access, you can check avaliable MISP instances, as Fidelis Barncat or [circl.lu](https://circl.lu/)

As an extra, at [secrepo](https://www.secrepo.com/) you will find lots of #infosec related datasets that you may find helpful if you already had defined  a research scope.